# Melhorar desempenho do file_get_contents em loops

Tags: php, codeigniter

Existe uma maneira de fazer o `file_get_contents` executar uma função rápida, dentro de um loop?

Segue o código

```
<?php foreach ($links->result() as $value) : ?>

<?php 
          $url = $value->lnkUrl;
          $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
          $web_link = "http://".$domain;

          $str = file_get_contents($web_link);

          if(strlen($str)>0){
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
             if ( isset( $title[1] ) ) {
               echo "<span class='directi_web' title='".$title[1]."'>". $title[1] ."</span>";
             }else{
                echo "<span class='directi_web'>...</span>";
             }
           }
?>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Uellington, a demora não está em si relacionada com o `file_get_contents` mas sim pelo fato do seu script baixar uma página inteira para extrair somente o título. Talvez `curl` seja o mais adequado para o que você deseja fazer.

Comment: E bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Se você descrever melhor qual o objetivo do seu código pode ficar de melhor entendimento e utilidade para outras pessoas. Faça um [tour] e veja o guia [ask] para entender melhor como funciona a comunidade.

Comment: Explicar o objetivo ajuda as pessoas a proporem soluções mais eficientes para seu problema.

Comment: Eu tenho um site que reúne conteúdos de vários sites na internet, é exibido em blocos na página inicial, e gostaria de exibir o nome do site de origem do link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o uso de [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para recolher a página e [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para extrair o título simplificas significativamente o trabalho realizado:

#### Função para recolher o HTML

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

#### O teu código fazendo uso do DOMDocument

```
foreach ($links->result() as $value) {

    // recolher página
    $domain = parse_url($value->lnkUrl, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $html = file_get_contents_curl("http://".$domain);

    // processar e recolher titulo
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // output
    if (!empty($title)) {
      echo '<span class="directi_web" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</span>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<span class="directi_web">...</span>';
    }
}
```

---

**Nota:** Este tipo de trabalhos deve ser realizado em *background* e a informação guardada em ficheiro ou base de dados. Na altura em que serves uma página ao visitante, os dados devem estar prontos a utilizar. Se estás a processar toda a informação na altura de apresentar a página, o visitante naturalmente tem que esperar e as coisas demoram muito mais do que é suposto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente funcionou, mas continua com um pouco de demora.
O background que você fala, seria um cache ?

Comment: Sim, essencialmente um código que recolhe e guarda os títulos e URLs das páginas numa tabela ou ficheiro, código esse a ser executado de X em X minutos. Assim no lado do _FrontEnd_, a consulta é apenas à caché tornando todo o processo super ágil!

Comment: Boa observação, ajudou muito. Abraços.